# Does pronouncing -ed ending of past tense verbs really matter?

Tags: past-tense, pronunciation

I am having a very hard time pronouncing the -ed ending of the past tense verb. When I hear a native speaker speaks these past tense verb, I hardly notice the -ed sound.
So could I ignore them? Or some of them?

Comment: I am not going to answer this question formally because I do not have the technical vocabulary to describe vocalization. But in American English the "ed" prefix to indicate the past tense and past participle of regular verbs is certainly voiced. What is probably confusing you is that the  "ed" is not voiced as a separate syllable (unless the final sound of the verb's root is a "d" or a "t" sound). So the past tense of "love," pronounced "luv," is pronounced as "luvd" rather than "luv-ed." The past tense of "greet," however," is pronounced "gree-ted."

Comment: If you ignore this sound you will be hard to understand at best. You will also certainly not be taken for a fluent speaker. This is an important one to practice!

Comment: @JeffMorrow isn't it more like "gree-tid" (with a short i sound like in "bit")?

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I was trying very hard to avoid the technicalities of describing the pronunciation of American English and its regional variations. In the regional dialect that I am most familiar with the sound appears to me to be closer to "ted" than "tid," but the fundamental point I was trying to make is that the "ed" suffix is not pronounced as a distinct syllable for most regular verbs in typical American speech. Consequently, the OP may not have been listening for the right thing.

Comment: Can you please tell me what your native language is?  American versus British English is simply not relevant here, as a standard type of English. The three different pronunciations (in simple terms, non-phonetic terms): are t, d or ted. But one does have to learn that the t, d or ted sound depends on the final sound in the verb. This site gives good examples: http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/learn-english/grammar/simple-past-pronunciation/ [What Jeff Morrow says is correct; love, luvd, greet, gree-ted, and face, face-ta, in non phonetic terms]

Comment: @Lambie Thank you very much for the example of "face." By the way, my mentioning American English was not to imply a distinction between American English and British English about the pronunciation of "ed." It was purely an admission of ignorance. Many dialects of British English are only semi-comprehensible to me. I would need sub-titles to watch "Shetlands" with full comprehension and would have welcomed sub-titles in "The Full Monty." I will no more make representations about British English than I would about Erse or Magyar.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. The /t/, /d/ or /id/ sound at the end of the(regular) past tense is noticed by native speakers. It is used to understand the time when an action occurred. Omitting the ending will make your speech hard to understand.

So this is an important thing to practice, in both speaking and listening.

Comment: Oh, so native speakers can notice there’s -ed or not. That helps boost my spirit to practice harder since I understand there’s possible to notice the -ed.