# Omitting the -ed ending?

Tags: pronunciation

I found [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154930/does-pronouncing-ed-ending-of-past-tense-verbs-really-matter) topic, according to the answers, it seems that the -ed ending of verbs shouldn't be omitted at all.

But when I learn from New Concept Engish, I heard this sentence:

> ' We mustn't buy things we don't need,' I **remark(ed)** suddenly.

The audio clip is [here](https://instaud.io/1XSY), feel free to check it out.

The -ed ending of the word *remark* is totally missed, is this correct or acceptable??

In another lesson, there is a similar [situation](https://instaud.io/1XSZ)

> He had been **confin(ed)** to the wooden box for over eighteen hours.

The -ed ending of *confine* is also missed, but I think it is due to word linking. I wonder if a native speaker can tell the difference between the room form and the -ed form of the verb.

Comment: Who told you that it's not there? It's absolutely there as it should be.

Comment: @Cookie Monster But I can't hear it, it's there in your mind instead of in reality I suppose.

Comment: I can't listen to the audio without signing up, but I can read the the transcript. It's clear enough from context that a native speaker would understand it whether or not it was there. Similarly, a native speaker very likely didn't notice the instance of "the the" which appeared in my first sentence; the mind extracts meaning without being too worried about how that meaning was conveyed.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens Audio link updated, now you can listen to it directly.

Comment: This US English speaker distinctly hears the **-ed** ending on "remarked".  It actually sounds more like a **-kt** sound in context; maybe that's what's confusing you?  I also hear it on "confined", although it is less clear there, partly because the **d** sound tends to run into the **t** sound of "to".

Comment: @stangdon Oh, I got it, she pronounces "remarked suddenly" as "/rɪ-mɑ:k-tsʌ-dən-lɪ/".

Comment: me too, as a foreigner I can't here the ed.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, using the past tense would be the normal choice. (but see below). You cannot omit the "ed" when you form the past tense.

The second example uses a past participle to form a verb in the passive voice. (the tense is carried by the  "has been" part) The "ed" cannot be omitted. In this example, omitting the "ed" is ungrammatical.

The speakers in the two examples do use the 'ed' ending in both cases. I  the first, the 'ed' is pronunced as an unaspirated [t], in the second the [d] of confined runs into the [t] of to. Nevertheless you should think of these as examples in which the pronunciation has been reduced, rather than omitted.

The first sentence is grammatical as present tense sentence if you use "I remark". The present tense has number of uses. One is called the "historical present" it is used by authors when writing a narrative about past events to create a sense of immediacy or a dramatic effect. It is not used in unemphasised English.

Comment: How about this? https://zh.forvo.com/phrase/it_seemed_to_exhale_a_silent_and_calm_authority/

Comment: What about it? if you have a new question you can ask it. But that link to a Chinese discussion of "It seemed to exhale a calm authority" doesn't seem relevant.